# Can you use slideshow in the header tag

Tags: instant, facebook-instant-articles

We have sent our Instant articles for review to Facebook and we got some complaints about our embeds in out articles.

Can you use slideshow in the header tag? It looks god in Pages app.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://someurl" >
<meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0">
</head>
<body>
<article>
<header>    <h1>Some header </h1>
<!-- The authors of your article -->
<!-- The date and time when your article was originally published -->
<time class="op-published" datetime="Fri, 19 May 2017 15:28:24 +0200" >19 May 2017</time>
<!-- The date and time when your article was last updated -->
<time class="op-modified" dateTime="Fri, 19 May 2017 15:28:24 +0200" >19 May 
2017</time>
<figure class="op-slideshow">
<figure>
    <img alt="alttext" src="https://someurl/Bilder_och_dokument/anton-nygren-och-simon-nystromjpg_672881.html/ALTERNATES/LANDSCAPE_1200/Anton%20Nygren%20och%20Simon%20Nystr%C3%B6m.jpg" /> 
    <figcaption>Text text.
        <cite>Photograf</cite>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</figure>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Instant articles review did go thru when we moved the slideshow from the header tagg.

On the page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/cover it says that media could be an Image or Video element to define the header for this article.